# Opencart filter module is not filtering

Tags: opencart

I am working with an opencart website. I have a problem when trying to make use of the filter module included in opencart. I get a filter in my category view, but it seems not to do any filtering.

[image: When filtered]

This is my approach: I created a basic color filter in `catalog->filters` with red, green and blue.

Secondly i've added red, green and blue to my products as filters in `catalog->products`.

Thirdly i've added the same filters to my categories that these products are connected to, `catalog->categories`.

Lastly, i've installed the filter module and set it as active and added it to my category-layout.

Is there something I am missing?

I am using opencart 1.5.6.4 with bearstore as theme.

Answer (score 2):

Normally will need to follow below steps for add Filter Module. So, please check it & follow below steps. May be, You have forgot to any step.

1. Go to Catalog > Filters and select Insert to create a filter group. Assign a filter group name (e.g. Color) and add filter name values (e.g. Blue, Red, Yellow).
2. Go to Catalog > Categories and Edit a category. Under the Data tab add the filters you want to be able to apply to that category (e.g. Color > Blue, Color > Red).
3. Go to Catalog > Products and Edit a product. Under the Links tab add the filters which apply to the product (e.g. Color > Blue). Apply to as many products as applicable.
4. Go to Extensions > Modules > Filter. If not installed select Install. Click Edit. Click the Add Module button and under Layout select Category and set Status to Enabled. Set whatever position and sort order you would like.

& also, Read this tutorial for more information http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-filters-in-opencart--cms-22594

Comment: Thanks for your respond. This is exactly what i've done multiple times, still the same outcome :/ Do you know what files I could debug to see if the filter actually is run? I have been trying to solve this for about 16 hours now and it is making me crazy!

Comment: I think, Here, You have use custom theme. So, First of all You will need to select default theme in your site. & then check it. is it working? yes/no. if, it is working in default OpenCart theme. So, May be, it is issue in custom theme. so you will need to contact custom theme support. if, it is not working in default opencart theme. so it is default opencart issue. So, You will need to contact http://www.opencart.com for this issue.

Comment: Hmh, after adding my custom theme and going back to default i get this problem:
`Notice: Error: Could not load template /www/webvol18/lp/x1rehfwylkoj2lo/xxx/public_html/catalog/view/theme/default/template/module/fblikebox.tpl! in /www/webvol18/lp/x1rehfwylkoj2lo/xxx/public_html/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-system_engine_controller.php on line 90`

Comment: Here, missing new module in your default theme. Go to catalog/view/theme/your custom theme /temp‌​late/module/  then find & copy fblikebox.tpl file. & then Go to catalog/view/theme/default/temp‌​late/module/ & then paste. & then check it with your site with default theme.

Comment: Thanks, got the default theme working again. The filtering still doesn't work though. I might need to contact opencart.com if someone else don't have something I could try out. This is just weird! :p